# Visual studio crashes when opening a Xaml page in admin but not normally

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Not sure about this one.

I have a project that opens fine in visual studio.

Because the solution hosts a WCF service it must berun as administrator.

If I run visual studio as an administrator and a particular xaml window is open as a tab, visual studio crashes a few seconds after opening and restarts.

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this or know why its happening?

Im getting round the problem by having an admin version with the screen closed and editing the screen in a non admin version.

Please let me know if I can provide anymore information.

Kind Regards

Ash

Answer (score 0):

I havent faced this issue before. But I would suggest filing a bug in http://connect.microsoft.com if you encounter this consistently. While filing the bug please include an example xaml file or solution, if the issue happens only with that particular file or solution.